# Minor loss coefficient for pipe end

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, pipelines

I want to estimate the head loss in a piping system. However, I don't know how to find or determine the loss coefficient for a connection point within the system.

At one point the pipe ends in a bigger tube where the fluid hits a cap and has to flow back around the pipe I have no clue on how to determine the loss at this intersection.
It is hard to explain so I have included a picture of the intersection hope this helps:

[image]

So my question is how can I determine the loss coefficient at this point if I want to determine the head loss as $h_L = KL \cdot \frac{v^2}{2\cdot g}$

Comment: Check out Coefficient of discharge

Comment: If the fluid path has a cap at the end of it, the flow will stop going down that path once the volume is full. If that is the only path for the fluid, then either something breaks due to pressure build up or the flow stops once the pressure equalizes throughout the system.

Comment: This is the only way of the fluid, and there will be some flow since there is a pump in the beginning of the system

Comment: As I understand it, you are trying to pump a liquid into a pipe that has no opening anywhere other than at the pump connection. The pump will work initially and the pipe will start to fill and then you will have problems when the air inside the pipe doesn't have anywhere to go. Even if we ignore the air, the liquid will not flow back around because the pump is moving the fluid in one direction - into the solid cap. This configuration will deadhead the pump. If I've misunderstood your setup, let me know.

Comment: The piping system has an opening at both the pump connection and at the other end (which has the configuration I tried to draw). The end of the pipe is located inside another larger pipe with a cap at the end. The fluid should then be able to flow around the pipe from the pump into a chamber.

Comment: At minimum, the velocity head from the flow in the smaller pipe is lost as the water fills up the larger pipe before the liquid starts to flow through the annular space made by the two pipes. I don't think this scenario would have a typical K value or equivalent length for head loss estimation.

Answer (score 1):

[[loss of head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2z0y.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2z0y.jpg)

1. For Sudden Enlargement d = mm = m i. Head Lost = x (Sh - 1) = mm of water ii. Discharge (Q)
   = Area of measuring Tank/time Required iii. Velocity (V) = Q A iv. Head lost he = (V1 – V2) 2 /2g
   2.For Sudden Contraction i. Head Lost = x(Sh - 1) = mm of water ii. Discharge (Q) = Area of
   measuring Tank * 0.1/time Required iii. Velocity (v) = Q A iv. Head loss hc =0.375 V2 2 /2g
2. For Bend i. Head Lost = x(Sh - 1) = mm of water ii. Discharge (Q)= Area of measuring Tank *
   0.1/time Required iii. Velocity (V) = Q A iv. Head lost hb = kV2 /2g (assume k=1)
3. For Elbow i. Head Lost = x(Sh - 1) = mm of water ii. Discharge (Q)= Area of measuring Tank *
   0.1/time Required iii. Velocity (V) = Q A iv. Head lost hel = kV2 /2g (assume k=1)
4. For Elbow i. Head Lost = x(Sh - 1) = mm of water ii. Discharge (Q)= Area of measuring Tank *

0.1/time Required iii. Velocity (V) = Q A iv. Head lost hel = kV2 /2g (assume k=1)
When there is any bend in a pipe, the velocity of flow changes, due to which separation of the

flow from the boundary and also formation of eddies takes place. Thus the energy is lost. Loss

of head in pipe due to bend is expressed as hb = k V2 /2g k is the coefficient of bend and its

value depends upon 1. Angle of bend 2. Radius of curvature 3. Diameter of the pipe
(d) Loss of head in elbow:- hel =k V2 /2g